# React.createElement with elements inside the string

Tags: reactjs, string, elementos

Tengo una aplicación que importa `geojson` con una propiedad que me gustaria renderizar.
La propiedad es un `string` con elementos dentro pero cuando intento renderizarla me convierte los elemenos anidados en texto.

**Ejemplo**:

```
React.createElement( 'div', null, "<div> algo </>")
```

**Nota**: No deseo crear un elmento con otros anidados, los elementos anidados ya vienen en el string que recupero en el `geojson`.

Gracias!

Comment: Hello, we are in Stackoverflow in Spanish please edit your question by translating it so it can be accepted and answered, also to prevent it from being closed ;)